# Getting data from a browser extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, screen-scraping, imacros, pagespeed, sikuli

My task is to fetch Google PageSpeed data for a website that requires login. According to research I've done, this is not possible for pages that require you to be logged in other than using a browser extension. I need to automate the process of running the extension for a list of pages and getting a count of the data.
My question is how do I extract data from a browser extension? The extension I'm using is Google PageSpeed API for Google Chrome browser. 
The possible options I've thought of is Sikuli script, or iMacros. But since I've never used these too much, I wanted to know if these tools can do what I'm looking for, or if there are any other better options.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give us web page you want to extract and what data you need?

Comment: Sikuli is irrelevant here. Use Selenium to automate the browser.